# Swapping two rows in a matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, swap, dynamic-arrays

I am having a problem in swapping two rows in a matrix that is a 2D-dynamic array. I wanted to know if there is a function to use directly or if there is none I would like to know how to make one. Thanks in advance.
Here is how I made the dynamic array:

```
int **ptrMatrix = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        ptrMatrix[i] = new int[column];
```

Comment: Perhaps `std::swap` or `std::swap_ranges`, depending on what a "2D-dynamic array" looks like.

Comment: Please update your answer to show us what you are referring to when saying "2D-dynamic array". Is it a dynamically allocated native 2D array or something else?

Comment: what is the difference between them if I may ask?

Comment: Why don't you use [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)? Example of [swap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/swap/).

Comment: Why don't you allocate one contiguous memory area:  MAX_ROWS * MAX_COLUMNS?  It will be more efficient to allocate and access.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution ... it is done simply by making a temporary variable (X) and appling the following code

```
for (int i=0;i<columns;i++)
{
   X=matrix[row1-1][i];
   matrix[row1-1][i]=matrix[row2-1][i];
   matrix[row2-1][i]=X;
}
```